# Reactjs FixedDataTable is sluggish when Chrome dev tools is open

Tags: reactjs

In my Reactjs application `FixedDataTable` with very basic setup is pretty fast in Chrome as long as Dev Tools is closed. 
It's painfully slow otherwise.

Interestingly [demo page](http://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/api-table.html) works fast regardless whether Dev Tools is open or not.

Am I missing any config tricks to make the component work fast?

Comment: I didn't know why the table was so slow, but then I found your question. Closing dev tools considerably sped up performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with `rowGetter` which was extracting a row from `ImmutableJS` using `.get(rowIndex).toJS()`. It happened to be very slow while Chrome Dev Tools is open.